# What is the procedure to using jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I downloaded everything from this [link](http://jqueryui.com/download/) (version 1.12.1).
After that I unzipped everything. So here's the thing, I have Wampserver downloaded and I'm working on a project in PHP with it. I dragged all of those items to the folder where my other codes are located.

I'm not good at Javascript or jQuery, but I want to use its "draggable" UI to make a moving "button"/image on a horizontal axis (so the person can agree or disagree). So, basically, how do I do that? Here's what I'm trying:

```
<script src="jQuery UI/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jQuery UI/jquery-ui.css"></script>
<script src="jQuery UI/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jQuery UI/jquery-ui.min.css"></script>
<script src="jQuery UI/jquery-ui.structure.css"></script>
<script src="jQuery UI/jquery-ui.structure.min.css"></script>
<script src="jQuery UI/jquery-ui.theme.css"></script>
<script src="jQuery UI/jquery-ui.theme.min.css"></script>
<script src="jQuery UI/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

<style>
#draggable {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: green;
}
</style>

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
        axis: "x";
    });
});
</script>

<br>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
<p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Could you please help by elaborating step-by-step for me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: make sure your scripts are at the bottom of your <body> tag

Comment: You don't include them all lol, only include jquery-ui.js and jquery-ui.css, min and the others are minified (smaller, less functions, compact) versions of the others for basic utilization

Comment: why does it have to be at the bottom?? Even after the div?? And thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Also include jquery.js **before** jquery-ui.js.

Comment: it still does not work! I can't drag my div :/

Comment: Check your console for errors. You shouldn't have a semi-colon after this term:  axis: "x";

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wbsfs1kv/. Always always always have the developer tools console open when developing (hit f12). If you had you would have seen that there was an unexpected ; and where.